# Launching the custom profile in Chrome for testing version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-for-testing

I am trying to run the following code, but I encounter a Driver's SessionNotCreatedException error.

Could you please have any ideaas how to specify a ChromeProfile when using Chrome For Testing?

> Error Code: Exception has occurred: SessionNotCreatedException
> Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
> (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The
> process started from chrome location
> C:\Windows\System32\chrome\win64-120.0.6099.109\chrome-win64\chrome.exe
> is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has
> crashed.)

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# set specify my profile
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
chrome_options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 05')

# set Chrome folder
chrome_options.binary_location = r'C:\Windows\System32\chrome\win64-120.0.6099.109\chrome-win64\chrome.exe'

# set ChromeDriver folder
driver_path = r'C:\Windows\System32\chromedriver\win64-120.0.6099.109\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'

# launch browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options=chrome_options)
# Open google
driver.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')

# waiting
time.sleep(3)

# close browser
driver.close()
```

I checked them below.. but seems not solved

- ・right folder pass
- ・could launch any website without specifying profile options.  　→it
  has launch Guest Mode. I want to launch with my profile.(not login)
- ・Im using same version(Chrome, Chrome Driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the user data dir of Chrome for Testing for macOS and Linux [here](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=chrome.*testing%20%2Bprofile%20-f:grd$%20-f:xtb%20f:chrome_paths&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc).

For Windows there's an extra layer of indirection, c.f. [here](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/4098409/4/chrome/install_static/user_data_dir_win_unittest.cc#b14).

Basically, change

```
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
```

to

```
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome for Testing\User Data')
```